# How to Decrypt the cookie in .NET 6 which is previously encrypted using Machine.Key Protect in .NET Framework App

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-6.0, session-cookies

.NET Framework Web app using CookieAuthentication and session store. Its encrypting the cookie value using MachineKey.Protect. Settings are available in web.config.

Web app calling .NET 6 API. API needs to verify the request using cookie information.

How .NET 6 API can decrypt this cookie?

`<machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" **decryption="AES"**/>`

Decryption in Web.config settings shows like 'AES'.

1. Tried to decrypt using AES in .NET 6 API. Its not working.
2. Tried to decrypt using IDataProtectionProvider by adding it to Servicescollection.
   var builder = services.AddDataProtection();
   Getting an exception "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider."

How to Decrypt the cookie in .NET 6 which is previously encrypted using Machine.Key Protect in .NET Framework App.

Comment: You'll probably need to copy the MachineKey source code from ASP.NET. You can find the .NET Framework source code at referencesource.microsoft.com.